# How to optimize double loops in a matrix while writing to a text file in python?

Tags: python, optimization

I have a python script to extract desired values from a matrix as follows:

```
count = 56000
with open('matrix.txt','w') as output:
    for i in range(count):
        for j in range(i + 1, count):
            score = dist(tmp[i],tmp[j]) #don't consider this calculation. It is just an example.
            output.write(f'{i},{j},{score}\n')
```

The matrix is very large and has a size 56000x56000. I need to apply the looping parameters as specified in the script. I'm calculating a score based on another function (not specified here). And writing the value of "i,j,score" as a row into a text file in each matrix iteration. This is taking an infinite amount of time and I don't know how to optimize this to reduce execution time for a large matrix. Can anybody please help me?

Comment: How slow is the function?  If it is slow, then we should look into optimizing it and/or computing one value from the previous value.

Comment: @Rick James this is very slow...and approximately takes 14+ days to complete execution.

Comment: Sounds like the "score" function might be taking a millisecond?

Comment: @Rick James yes...is there a way to optimize this?

Comment: Let's see the function.

Answer (score 1):

If your matrix fits in memory, the best would be to compute and store it in a numpy ndarray and then use [np.save()](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.save.html) to save the matrix to a file (it is fast and use binary format, you can even use compression with [np.savez_compressed](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.savez_compressed.html)).
If it does not fit in memory, I would advise to split it in N parts (by row for example) and use the same solution as above for each of the parts.
Here is some code as example for a matrix which fits in RAM :

```py
import numpy as np

count = 56000
mat = np.zeros((count, count), dtype="float32")  # create a matrix of zeros, if this line succeeds hoora your matrix fits in memory
# mat will take 12.5 GB with float32 (56000^2 x 4 Bytes)

for i in range(count):
    for j in range(i + 1, count):
        mat[i, j] = compute_some_value(i, j)

np.save("matrix.txt", mat)
```

**But to get faster computation speed try to avoid for loops and use numpy functions and vectorization has much as possible.**

Comment: Could you please let me know how to alter the script for that? I'm quite new to python.

Comment: I need to save 3 values in the matrix.txt file: value of i, value of j, and a computed value from i and j. Where should I change it to get that?

Comment: I would not store i and j because the matrix is already huge and storing i and j would triple the memory usage. Moreover it is useless to store i and j as there are the indices of the value stored so you can retrieve them when you read the matrix.

Answer (score 0):

If the file format has some flexibility, then start a "line" with the starting i,j, then have the scores for the row.

This cuts back on the formatting and I/O, both of which cost a noticeable amount of time.

This may require changes to the reader, but those may be beneficial, too.

A minor optimization:

```
for i in range(count):
    tmpi = tmp[i]          # do the subscription only once per row
    for j in range(i + 1, count):
        score = dist(tmpi,tmp[j])  # this changed, too
```

Ditto for anything that can be pulled out from the score_function.

Comment: what is the initialization for "tmp" here?

Comment: I don't know where tmp comes from.  It was not defined in the Question either.